# Stop method/interval if user disconnects or condition is met

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, setinterval

I want to create a live order page where clients can see the status of their order.

For that reason I want to run a function every 10 seconds that checks the SQL database if the order is ready.

```
function checkOrder(socket, userid, checkinterval) {



    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        // Use the connection
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user = ' + userid + ' ORDER BY timestamp DESC', function(err, rows) {

            var alldone = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if (rows[i]['status'] == 'completed') {
                    alldone = true;
                } else {
                    alldone = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            socket.emit('order-update', rows);
            connection.release();

            if (alldone) {
                console.log('all done');
                socket.emit('execute', '$("#orderstatus").html(\'Done\');');
                clearInterval(checkinterval);

            }


        });
    });



}

var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var app = express();
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("chain.pem")
};
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var port = 443;

server.listen(port, function() {

    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);

});


io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('trackorder', function(userid) {
        var checkinterval = setInterval(function() {
            checkOrder(socket, userid, checkinterval);
        }, 10000);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {


        clearInterval(checkinterval);


    });

});
```

Now I'm having issues on stopping the function if either the job is completed or the client disconnects.

How could I achieve that? I suppose the `clearInterval()` would work inside the function since it is passed but there is an issue with the `on disconnect` event handler. Either `checkinterval` is undefined or if I define it globally it stops the wrong function.

How can this be done properly?

Comment: Simply dont use intervals for asynchronous stuff. If that is delayed to much youve got concurrent requests running. Simply use a recursive setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkInterval` variable is out of scope when the `disconnect` event comes.  You need to move its definition up a level.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // checkInterval variable is declared at this scope so all event handlers can access it
    var checkInterval;
    socket.on('trackorder', function(userid) {
        // make sure we never overwrite a checkInterval that is running
        clearInterval(checkInterval);
        checkInterval = setInterval(function() {
            checkOrder(socket, userid, checkInterval);
        }, 10000);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        clearInterval(checkinterval);
    });
});
```

In addition:

1. I added a guard against overwriting the `checkInterval` variable if you ever get the `trackorder` event more than once for the same client.
2. You mispelled `checkinterval` in one place.
3. As others have said, polling your database on behalf of every single client is a BAD design and will not scale.  You need to either use database triggers (so it will tell you when something interesting changed) or have your own code that makes relevant changes to the database trigger a change.  Do not poll on behalf of every single client.
4. You have no error handling in either `pool.getConnection()` or `connection.query()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that complicated setInterval stuff, just add a small IIFE that calls itself if the result isnt there yet. Some pseudocode:

```
function checkOrder(socket, userid){ 
 //a variable pointing to the running timer
 var timer;
 //on error clear
 socket.on("disconnect", ()=>clearTimout(timer));
 //a small IIFE
 (function retry(){
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    //parse & notice socket
    if (!alldone) //retry
      timer = setTimeout(retry, 1000);
  });
 })();
}
```

Comment: How would I stop the checking if a user disconnects in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're using a bad approach. You should go for **push** rather than **pull**.

What I mean is, emit the event when status of order changes. Don't put the burden on your database to hit it frequently for no reason.

On successful change of status, emit the event `order_status_update` with `order id` and what is the `new status`

```
socket.emit('order_status_update', {order_id: 57, status: 'In Process'});
```

This way you don't need any kind of loop or setinterval etc. No worries even if client is connected or not, its `sockat.io` business to take care of it. You will just raise the event.